# what are the new features introduced in java5?

Tags: java, java-5

Can anyone explain what are the new features introduced in java5 over older versions of java with some simple examples to understand the concept.?

Comment: You can google it. You will find some good links.

Comment: "Release notes Java 5" are good keywords for googling: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/relnotes.html

Comment: Java 5.0 was EOLed many years ago. Java 6 will be EOLed this year. Perhaps its time to skip to Java 7. ;) BTW There never was a "Java 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read from the oracle page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html